# How to set a default value with Html.TextBoxFor?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2, html-helper

Simple question, if you use the Html Helper from ASP.NET MVC Framework 1 it is easy to set a default value on a textbox because there is an overload `Html.TextBox(string name, object value)`.  When I tried using the *Html.TextBoxFor* method, my first guess was to try the following which did not work:

```
<%: Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Age, new { value = "0"}) %>
```

Should I just stick with Html.TextBox(string, object) for now?

Comment: use this <%: Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Age, new { Value = "0"}) %>  ,make  a small change V capital in Value.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

It turns out that if you don't specify the Model to the View method within your controller, it doesn't create a object for you with the default values.

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
public ViewResult Create()
{
  // Loads default values
  Instructor i = new Instructor();
  return View("Create", i);
}

[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
public ViewResult Create()
{
  // Does not load default values from instructor
  return View("Create");
}
```

Comment: More likely it is MVC bug or feature, since Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password, new { class = "form-control", value ="default" is rendered into almost the same html, and the "default" go to value being displayed successfully. For example, value=Model.Email works, but value=ViewBag.Email does work. So this accepted answer is better and cleaner, not so hacking.

Comment: What is `Instructor`?

Answer (score 390):

Try this:

```
<%= Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Age, new { @Value = "0"}) %>
```

note that `@Value` has a capital `V`

Comment: Curious to know why capital 'V' works and lowercase 'v' does not? Also, this solution overrides the model value for Age, even if one is present.

Comment: value with small v is keyword for C# http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx. So i think thats why it doesn't work.

Comment: Upvoted the comment because one upvote for an answer this obscure and insightful seemed... inadequate.

Comment: It is still curious that @value doesn't work. readonly is also a keyword for C# but @readonly works without any problems.

Comment: The html source in browser is <input Value="0" id="Age" name="Age" type="text" value="" /> when using @Value. There're both "Value" with "0" and "value" with "" in the input tag.

Comment: What would be the same for Vb.net?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14142511/textboxfor-value-uppercase-instead-value

Comment: in this answer is correct. value = "0" this will not work. Value = "0" this will work. Because V is capital letter. need to include at also.

Comment: `value` is a contextual keyword in C#, and only as special meaning in property getters and setters. My guess is that the MVC code is hard coded to look for "Value" because MS intends you to always use PascalCase property names since that's their typical convention and to avoid conflicts with non-contextual keywords such as `class`. It all gets rendered in the HTML as lowercase anyway. [more](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15271804/145173)

Comment: How to achieve same with "TextAreaFor" ? default values plus row and col

Comment: I'd like to add that this may be the solution for MVC 1, but for any newer version this is unncessary. You shouldn't need to specify @Value, the HtmlHelpers should automatically show a value in the textbox if the model property already has a value. I'm not sure on which version of MVC this was added, but it's something to keep in mind.

Comment: **NEVER** set the `value` attribute when using `HtmlHelper` methods. You set the value of the property in the GET method before you pass the model to the view.

Answer (score 63):

This should work for MVC3 & MVC4

```
 @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Age, new { @Value = "12" })
```

If you want it to be a hidden field

```
 @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Age, new { @Value = "12",@type="hidden" })
```

Comment: For hidden fields, just use
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Age, new { @Value = "12" })

Comment: good one
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Age, new { @Value = "12" }) not wokring

Comment: And why would you hide an hard coded default value like this ? non sense

Answer (score 22):

The default value will be the value of your `Model.Age` property. That's kind of the whole point.

Comment: Seems it is bad idea when model manages default values.
What should be done when different default value needs for same collection of model items?

Comment: @RredCat Agreed, this muddies the separation of the UI layer

Answer (score 21):

You can simply do :

```
<%= Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Age, new { @Value = "0"}) %>
```

or better, this will switch to default value '0' if the model is null, for example if you have the same view for both editing and creating :

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Age, new { @Value = (Model==null) ? "0" : Model.Age.ToString() })
```

Answer (score 13):

This work for me

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Age, htmlAttributes: new { @Value = "" })
```

Comment: +1 for the named parameter that is especially helpful in copy/pastable code and one that uses a method with many overloads

Answer (score 11):

value="0" will set defualt value for @Html.TextBoxfor

its case sensitive
"v" should be capital

Below is working example:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Nights, 
    new { @min = "1", @max = "10", @type = "number", @id = "Nights", @name = "Nights", Value = "1" })
```

Answer (score 9):

Here's how I solved it. This works if you also use this for editing.

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Age, new { Value = Model.Age.ToString() ?? "0" })
```

Comment: if Age is null.. you're going to get a null pointer exception because the ?? is going to attempt to check the return of the ToString().

Comment: @eaglei22 Nullable<T>.ToString() will return an empty string if the value is null.

Comment: thank you for showing how to model bind in an anonymous object

Answer (score 8):

Using `@Value` is a hack, because it outputs two attributes, e.g.:

```
<input type="..." Value="foo" value=""/>
```

You should do this instead:

```
@Html.TextBox(Html.NameFor(p => p.FirstName).ToString(), "foo")
```

Answer (score 8):

this worked for me   , in this way we setting the default value  to empty string

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Id, new { @Value = "" })
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some context, explaining how it works and when to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.

Comment: @Bono added some comments

Answer (score 5):

If you have a partial page form for both editing and adding, then the trick I use to default value to `0` is to do the following:

```
@Html.TextBox("Age", Model.Age ?? 0)
```

That way it will be `0` if unset or the actual age if it exists.

Comment: If Age is an int, that won't work; It would need to be a nullable int.

Answer (score 2):

For .net core 5 setting value in htmlAttributes seems doesnt work. But you can use workaround:

```
var ageTextBox = (TagBuilder) Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Age);
ageTextBox.Attributes.Remove("value");
ageTextBox.Attributes.Add("value", "value you want to set");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this also, that is remove new { } and replace it with string.

```
<%: Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Age,"0") %>
```