# how to setup a default value like datatime.now for [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3-areas

I would like to know if is possible to set a default value for an attribute on my class in MVC asp.net 3.

At the moment I'm using this:

```
[DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
```

Comment: What do you exactly mean under default value for an attribute?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe what you want is here: [How to set a default value with Html.TextBoxFor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3034986/how-to-set-a-default-value-with-html-textboxfor)