# TextBoxFor @Value (uppercase) instead @value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, keyword, html.textboxfor

**This is just for curiosity**

Why does this code work:

```
Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Age, new { @Value = "0"})
```

and this doesn't:

```
Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Age, new { @value = "0"})
```

*Note the uppercase 'V' in `@Value`*

I know `value` is a keyword, but so is `readonly` and it works. It's not necessary to use `@Readonly` (with uppercase 'R').

Does anybody have a clue?

Comment: Value is reserved, while value isnt.

Comment: What do you mean by "work"/"doesn't work"?

Comment: @CodesInChaos see the comments here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3287411/310276

Comment: 1) Yours uses `@value` not `value`, so `value` being a keyword shouldn't matter. 2) Even with `value` it should work, since `value` is no keyword in an initializer. | So this doesn't seem like a simple C# issue to me, but rather like a ASP.net MVC/`TextBoxFor` issue. I suspect a property called `value` has a special meaning for `TextBoxFor` and not for C#.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure but, that could be `value` is a keyword in properties, `readonly` isn't. Look at [properties from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx).

[image]

[image]

Comment: Doesn't make sense to me. The `@` should escape the keyword, so `@value` results in a property called `value`. If this doesn't work, it must be some weirdness related to `TextBoxFor` or Razor and not simply due to being a C# keyword.

Comment: It makes sense because it's not just a reserved work. Inside a setter, it's a method parameter.

Comment: Just try it with some other C# keyword that's not special cased by `TextBoxFor`.

Comment: I agree with @CodesInChaos. It does not make sense. It is actually a consequence of the MVC framework that always overwrites the `value` attribute as described in @CodesInChaos answer.

Answer (score 6):

[`InputExtensions.TextBoxFor`](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/sourcecontrol/latest#src/System.Web.Mvc/Html/InputExtensions.cs) special cases cases a few attribute names, among them `value`(case sensitive). This is unrelated to C# keywords.

In particular the value obtained from the `expression` parameter takes precedence of a property called `value` you pass into the `htmlAttributes` parameter.

Taking a look at your example:

- If you use `Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Age, new { @value = "0"})` it will compile, but `TextBoxFor` will override the `value` attribute with the value `x.Age` evaluates to.
- If you use `Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Age, new { @Value = "0"})` it will compile, and you will get two entries in the attribute dictionary, one `Value` that's `"0"`, and one `value`, that's `x.Age`.

  I expect the output to be something nonsensical like `<input  Value="0" value="..." type="text"/>`.

Comment: It is not rendering both `Value` and `value`. It renders just `value`. (Mvc 4 and Razor 2)

Comment: I just checked and it is rendering both `Value` and `value` with ASP.NET MVC 3 and ASPX views

Comment: Using both Firefox' and Chrome's "inspect element" will show only one `value` attribute. However, using "view source" or something similar will reveal that there is indeed both a `Value` and a `value` attribute. It seems the browser just shows the first occurrence of `value`, no matter the case. Indeed, it also works with `vAlue` (tested just now). MVC 4 and Razor 2.

Comment: @dlebech thanks, I also saw Edge's inspector showing only one value attribute, but you're right, the source shows two attributes.  For this reason I'm using the TextBox helper instead (because it has an explicit parameter for setting the value attribute)

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the MVC code is hard coded to look for `Value` because a MS engineer intended you to always use PascalCase property names, since that's their typical convention and PascalCase avoids conflicts with non-contextual keywords such as `class`. Notice how PascalCase properties get rendered in the HTML as lowercase.

The reason is not about `value` being a keyword, since it's a *contextual* keyword in C# and only has special meaning (and thus turns blue in the IDE) in property getters and setters. It has no special meaning in the anonymous type passed to `TextBoxFor`.

Comment: It also works with `vAlue`. It depends on the browser rendering. See my comment for the answer by CodesInChaos.