# ASP.net MVC HTML5 Toolkit - support default textbox values?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-4, codeplex

I stumbled on the [ASP.net MVC HTML5 Toolkit](http://www.deanhume.com/Home/BlogPost/asp-net-mvc-html5-toolkit/29) and it looks great. However, I don't see any way to include a default value for HTML5 textboxes whereas this is possible using the standard MVC textbox.

Outside of Javascript, is it possible to add a default value to HTML5 textboxes from this toolkit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this helps - you can actually add default values using the MVC HTML5 toolkit.
The code will look something like this:

```
@Html.Html5TextBox("Name", InputTypes.InputType.Text, new { @Value = "Dean" })
```

And can be applied to any of the elements in the toolkit. For more details, take a look at this answer:

[How to set a default value with Html.TextBoxFor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3034986/how-to-set-a-default-value-with-html-textboxfor)